# How to install tensorflow cpu for inference on AWS EC2

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

I have amazon EC2 server. I installed TensorFlow-cpu for inference purpose using `pip install tensorflow-cpu`
But I give my following error

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is opti           mized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-cri           tical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-03-26 01:56:05.690616: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 230004000           0 Hz
2021-03-26 01:56:05.690795: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f19948b5500 initia           lized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-03-26 01:56:05.690811: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host           , Default Version
2021-03-26 01:56:06.163095: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR op           timization passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

Is there any solution

Comment: Its a warning not an error.

Comment: but its not giving any result, though gpu tensorflow giving